# Image broken on web page, but works when testing elsewhere

Tags: html, css

I have a simple block of code which should display a Facebook icon:

```
<div class="icon">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" onclick="window.open(' https://www.facebook.com/','newwindow','width=600, height=300');return false;">
        <img src="https://content.t-three.co.uk/hubfs/tp-2017/Template%20refresh/Littlebooks/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

On the page, it shows as a broken image, but when I've tested the code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6aa3q6p5/), it works? (Image is white, might need to drag the image to see it).

Why is this happening?

**Edit**:

Here's a [preview link][2] to the test page.

Comment: What error message does the console, in browser DevTools (chrome) IDE, display?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I've edited the question with a link, might be able to display the issue better.

Comment: Change the image protocols in the `src` and `srcset` attributes to secure `https:` - a "Mixed Content" issue where the page is loaded over `https:` but the browser requests an insecure image, or an image from an insecure source, "the content must be served over HTTPS."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_151499454550556" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_raw_html" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="raw_html"><!-- Facebook -->
<div class="icon">
    <a return="false" href="facebook.com" onclick="window.open(' facebook.com/', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=300');
    return false;"> 
        <img src="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png"  srcset="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png">
    </a>
</div>
<!-- LinkedIn -->
<div class="icon">
    <a return="false" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/t-three-consulting" onclick="window.open(' https://www.linkedin.com/company/t-three-consulting', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=300');
    return false;">
        <img src="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/linkedin.png" alt="LinedIn" srcset="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/linkedin.png">
    </a>
</div>
<!-- Twitter -->
<div class="icon">
    <a return="false" href="https://twitter.com/tthreetweet" onclick="window.open(' https://twitter.com/tthreetweet', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=300');
    return false;">
        <img src="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" srcset="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/twitter.png">
    </a>
</div>
<!-- GPlus -->
<div class="icon">
    <a return="false" href="https://www.facebook.com" onclick="window.open(' https://www.facebook.com/', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=300');
    return false;">
        <img src="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png" alt="GPlus" srcset="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png">
    </a>
</div>
<!-- Email -->
<div class="icon">
    <a return="false" href="https://www.facebook.com" onclick="window.open(' https://www.facebook.com/', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=300');
    return false;">
        <img src="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png" alt="Email" srcset="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png">
    </a>
</div>
<!-- Email -->
<div class="icon">
    <a return="false" href="https://www.facebook.com" onclick="window.open(' https://www.facebook.com/', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=300');
    return false;">
        <img src="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png"  srcset="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png">
    </a>
</div></span>
```

also remove this code

Remove this script from page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

if(!$('.404-page').length)
{
  $(".hs-landing-page a[href*='facebook.com']").find("img").attr("src","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png").attr("srcset","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png");
  $(".hs-landing-page a[href*='linkedin.com']").find("img").attr("src","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/linkedin.png").attr("srcset","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/linkedin.png");
  $(".hs-landing-page a[href*='twitter.com']").find("img").attr("src","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/twitter.png").attr("srcset","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/twitter.png");
  $(".hs-landing-page a[href*='plus.google.com']").find("img").attr("src","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/google-plus.png").attr("srcset","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/google-plus.png");
  $(".hs-landing-page a[href*='mailto:']").find("img").attr("src","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/email.png").attr("srcset","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/email.png");
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: I've just tried 
'<a return="false" href='https://www.facebook.com' onclick="window.open(' https://www.facebook.com/','newwindow','width=600, height=300');return false;">
  <img src="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png" srcset"//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png"/>
    </a>' - Still the same issue?

Comment: I check preview link. But don't found change you mentioned

Comment: I've reverted it back since I had no success. I've added it back. You can check the link now.

Comment: https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=1870680&tc_deviceCategory=desktop&template_layout_id=5498485491   I checked here but still there is path with http://

Comment: can you edit your answer to show the complete block of code (like in my question) - just so I can see your finished product?

Comment: Thanks. I've pretty much just copied your code, and tested it again - still the same issues unfortunately. You can see it in the preview link

Comment: I see but there is no such code. Please share preview link here again

Comment: https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=1870680&tc_deviceCategory=desktop&template_layout_id=5498485491

Comment: I can see that some java script code change Image src value. Please take look into it. I try to figure out but script are minified

Comment: Even if I remove the onclick and just have <div class="icon">
    <a href="facebook.com">
        <img src="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png"  srcset="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png">
    </a>
</div> Still the image doesn't load

Comment: Ahh, removing the 404 JS seems to have done the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay now with the link it's easier, you have mixed secure and insecure content (i.e. http and httpS). Go to your browser's developer tools (usually F12 key) and you will see these errors:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=1870680&tc_deviceCategory=desktop&template_layout_id=5498485491' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

It either all needs to be "http" or "https", you cannot mix the 2. Your browser consider that you are loading insecure content on a secure page.

So:

`<img src="httpS://...`

Comment: This had more likely to be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Yeah sorry, still new at this... I have edited it to be an answer. Is that better? :)

Comment: Yes now perfect !

Comment: @AlixBergeret Thanks for your answer. I've changed all the links in my code to 'https://...', but still the same issue arises?

Comment: For some reason if you have a bit of JS near the top that rechanges all the https into http, here: $( document ).ready(function() {

if(!$('.404-page').length)
{
  $(".hs-landing-page a[href*='facebook.com']").find("img").attr("src","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png").attr("srcset","http://content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Page/facebook.png");

Comment: Even if I remove the onclick and just have <div class="icon"> <a href="facebook.com"> <img src="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing_Pa‌​ge/facebook.png" srcset="//content.t-three.com/hubfs/Images/Templates/Landing‌​_Page/facebook.png"> </a> </div> Still the image doesn't load

Comment: Again the JS on lines 41-52 replace all src values to http ones. You need to comment that block of code out.